# Print sums of more than one column in Linux

Tags: linux, perl, sed, awk, grep

I want to get sums of two columns' values. I want each result separately. Here is my values:

**command**

```
iostat -x 1 2 \
| perl -e 'local $/=""; @p=<STDIN>; print @p[4];' \
| awk '{ print $6 " " $7}' \
| grep -v rsec
```

**output**

```
0.00 1608.00
22.00 0.00
10.00 1608.00
0.00 1312.00
0.00 0.00
0.00 0.00
0.00 296.00
```

**I want this result**

```
32.00 4824.00
```

Here is what i tried:

```
iostat -x 1 2 \
| perl -e 'local $/=""; @p=<STDIN>; print @p[4];' \
| awk '{ print $6 " " $7}' \
| grep -v rsec \
| awk '{ SUM += $1 SUM2 += $2} END { print SUM " " SUM2}'
```

This command gives me a syntax error. What's the solution for this?

Comment: Just add a `;` in between `SUM += $1` and `SUM2 += $2`--->  `{SUM += $1; SUM2 += $2}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the man page, commands in `awk` can be separated by newlines, semicolons, or both. Your two commands are not separated by any of those things. The solution is to write:

```
| awk '{ SUM += $1; SUM2 += $2} END { print SUM " " SUM2}'
```